# Validating reCaptcha on asp.net form

Tags: asp.net, validation, captcha

I have included this in my .ascx file

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
<div class="g-recaptcha" style="max-width:100%; width:300px;margin:0 auto;" data-sitekey="I_PUT_MY_SITEKEY_HERE"></div>
```

and here is what's in my .ascx.cs file

```
protected void SubmitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.Validate();
    if (Page.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
            //this is where all the email template code is, not important
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Error("Contact Form", ex);
        }
    }

}
```

As you can see I am trying to validate the captcha on the submit button click, then if it is valid, then the email is sent through the contact form. Where am I going wrong? The captcha is displaying fine, just need it to work with the form.

Answer (score 0):

Page.IsValid only validates asp.net controls. Validating ReCaptcha needs extra work. You can read how in https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify